# Alpha VMS VAX - printer queue changes

Tags: openvms

I have an old legacy VMS VAX (Alpha) server that's still used for a program called Vango.

The VAX is located at 192.168.1.2

We have an existing server that's being replaced, which is currently running SBS 2003, and it's at 192.168.1.148. It's DNS name is, "Server"

Basically, we'd like to install the new server with a different name and a different IP address from the old windows server. But, in order to do this, we need to be able to change the VAX queue location for the print queues:

```
$ show queue
Printer queue 600TCP, idle, on ALPHA::"600TCP:9100", mounted form DZPLOT
 (stock=DEFAULT)
  <600TCP>

Printer queue 650TCP, idle, on ALPHA::"650TCP:9100", mounted form COLOR
   (stock=DEFAULT)
  <650TCPLIBRARY=650TCP_DEVCTL>

Printer queue HP1100, idle, on ALPHA::"HP1100:9100", mounted form HPLJ
  <HP1100>

Generic printer queue HP600

Generic printer queue HP650

Generic printer queue HPLJ

Terminal queue LTA12, idle, on ALPHA::LTA12:, mounted form HPLJ

Terminal queue LTA18, idle, on ALPHA::LTA18:, mounted form PLOT

Terminal queue LTA19, idle, on ALPHA::LTA19:, mounted form PLOT

Printer queue MOPIER, idle, on ALPHA::"MOPIER:9100", mounted form HPLJ
  <MOPIER>

Batch queue SYS$BATCH, idle, on ALPHA::

Batch queue SYS$NIGHT, idle, on ALPHA::

  Entry  Jobname         Username             Status
  -----  -------         --------             ------
    317  DAILYBACK       SYSTEM               Holding until 16-AUG-2012 03:00:00

Terminal queue SYS$PRINT, idle, on ALPHA::LTA11:, mounted form DEFAULT
$
```

But, to be honest, I don't know how to change the print queue to point it to the new server name and IP address.

What I need is the actual commands to type into the VAX shell to change the server/device name for the queue so that it will now point to the new windows server.

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, the output from `show queue/device/full` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to change anything in the queues if you change how the names 600TCP, 650TCP, etc. are resolved on your network, either via DNS or in the local host database.  And that assumes the printers themselves have changed IP address, which doesn't sound like the case from your description.

I don't actually see how "Server" is involved at all since the printer queues all seem to be pointing directly to the printers on the standard HP Laserjet port of 9100, so unless the installation of the new server has some more global network change going along with it, you may not need to change anything on the Alpha (and if it's an Alpha, it's not a VAX -- those are two entirely different processor architectures, but both do run VMS).

If you do want to recreate the queues, I suggest acquiring fixque.com from one of the freeware collections that has it such as [this one](http://www.decuslib.com/decus/freewarev50/fixque/).  That will generate commands that can recreate all of your queues, as well as forms and everything else in your queue database.  Just pull out the INITIALIZE command for the queue you are interested in and edit it appropriately.  For example, to change the hostname of a remote printer from LITTLEHP to BIGHP, edit the part of the command looking like:

```
/ON=ALPHA::"LITTLEHP:9100"
```

to:

```
/ON=ALPHA::"BIGHP:9100"
```

Then do STOP/QUEUE/RESET *queuename*, followed by DELETE/QUEUE *queuename*, then run the INITIALIZE command to recreate it.